# If you control the playback and mute of music through js

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am a beginner in programming. I would like to ask if I write a music player that I want to be able to click to play and click again to mute. How should I write it? I

have tried several times and failed.

PS. Because I don't know how to put the music file on the Internet, the current music file is invalid, it is purely indicative.

```js
//關閉
let tag = true;
let music = document.querySelector('#music');
let btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // 如果目前 flag 不是關閉就撥放
    if (tag) {
    // music.pause();
    music.setAttribute("muted","true");
    btn.setAttribute("class", "pause");
    tag = false;
    } else {
    music.play();
    btn.setAttribute("class", "play");
    tag = true;
    }
});
```

```css
body{
  height: 500vh;
}
.btn {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmxXsF6UrJ0o-wcYdmXOqSpxZXhMzgcCzyAA&usqp=CAU');
  background-size: cover;
}

.play{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 1s;
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmxXsF6UrJ0o-wcYdmXOqSpxZXhMzgcCzyAA&usqp=CAU');
  background-size: cover;
}

.pause {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 1s;
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScVjEwKCmnfciiCoEZ6am7ZXoIaVR0rUE_O2H1xWkqDMOZV-mk7i8eMwktqV9nHCsyF3A&usqp=CAU');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<audio id="music" controls="controls">
  <source src="demo.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<div class="btn"></div>
```

Comment: Do you really just want to _mute_ the playing track (then it will _continue_ playing in the background, the user just won't hear anything)? Or do you perhaps actually rather want to _pause_ it?

Comment: `play` and `pause` methods exist, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play

Comment: @CBroe

I originally wanted to suspend him, but the demand I received was to mute and not suspend!

So I'm in trouble

Comment: So what exactly about this is not currently working? Without an audio file, it is a bit hard to test.

Comment: Sorry, my example doesn't provide files that can play music!
Because I don't know how to make music available on the Internet, or do you know how to put music on the Internet to make audio play music

Comment: Upload it somewhere on your server, so that you can specify an absolute URL in the example ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to play and pause the audio on click,
then this code might solve your problem but if you want to mute the audio then you can use `music.muted = true`

HTML

```
<audio id="music" controls="controls">
      <source
        src="https://soundbible.com/mp3/service-bell_daniel_simion.mp3"
        type="audio/mp3"
      />
    </audio>
    <div class="btn"></div>
```

CSS

```
body {
      height: 100vh;
      display: grid;
      place-items: center;
    }

    .btn {
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      transition: 1s;
      background: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmxXsF6UrJ0o-wcYdmXOqSpxZXhMzgcCzyAA&usqp=CAU");
      background-size: cover;
    }

    .btn.paused {
      transition: 1s;
      background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScVjEwKCmnfciiCoEZ6am7ZXoIaVR0rUE_O2H1xWkqDMOZV-mk7i8eMwktqV9nHCsyF3A&usqp=CAU");
      background-size: cover;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Javascript

```
const music = document.querySelector("#music");
      const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
      var playing = false;

      btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (!playing) {
          music.play();
          btn.classList.toggle("paused");
          playing = true;
        } else {
          music.pause();
          btn.classList.toggle("paused");
          playing = false;
        }
      });
```